# VoiceOver selecting multiple items when navigating through collection view instead of just one

Tags: swift, macos, voiceover

I'm currently adding VoiceOver support to a MacOS application (using AppKit) and running into an issue where VoiceOver is adding items contained within a NSCollectioView to it's selection instead of moving the selection from 1 item to another. I'm struggling to find a way to force VoiceOver to limit itself to a single item as it navigates over the collection. I tried forcing the collection view to disallow multiple selection but that didn't appear to help. Reviewed the app using XCode's Accessibility Inspector but everything looks good as far as I can tell - Role shows as AXList, subrole as AXCollectionList.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved my issue. It wasn't specifically related to VoiceOver but how the collection view was handling selections. Fixed the problem by implementing `func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, shouldSelectItemsAt indexPaths: Set<IndexPath>) -> Set<IndexPath>`